# Adding multiple excel sheet and summing dynamic number of worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to merge multiple excel files into one workbook. However, after I merged the worksheets into another workbook, Those worksheets that has links to the previous workbooks are all broken.
I wanted to sum all the worksheets in their specific fields in a "Total" worksheet in the new workbook as well.

Please help.

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(filename:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy After:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next

                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that all your **sheets have same structure** and you just want to sum them up then you can use built in function SUM in your Total sheet.

You can set range and then add formula to whole range at once (i have only 3 sheets 1,2,3 and total).

```
Dim xRng as Range, n as integer

n = Thisworkbook.Sheets.Count
Set xRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n).Range("A2:D2")

xRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & ThisWorkbook.sheets(1).name & "':'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n-1).name & "'!RC)"
```

Also it is good to use dynamic range using Last row and last column or named ranges...

I hope this helps atleast a bit :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! What if the number of sheets are dynamic? How can I modifiy your code to include the dynamic number of sheets being added?

Comment: Assuming that your dynamic sheets are from 1 to n and n is Total then you can use something like edited in this commented post...

Comment: I tried the edited code and It was unable to run. Yes, the dynamic sheets runs from 1 to n.There was an object defined error. AM I missing something?

Comment: I realised there is nothing wrong with the code, however, my worksheet name has SPACES, which resulted in the run time error. is there anyway I can work around this? I must keep the spaces from the worksheet as it is coming from another workbook.

Comment: Hello, check new code again... It contains new characters ' which is used when workbook/worksheet can have spaces... "=SUM('" & ThisWorkbook.sheets(1).name & "' see in my answer full example.